# I am using Bulma and I am getting some bugs in my website

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working on a web app and I am using Bulma for first-time, I don't know why but I am getting a very unexpected bugs, that is, my background color i.e black doesn't seem to be appear onto the page.

[image]

here is my CSS code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Home Page
{% endblock title %}
<style>
    body{
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

in base.html from which I have extended this page, there too I have wrote this following css:

```
<style>
    body{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

**Please help me with this, Thanks in advance~**

**EDIT:**

I found out that whenever I put any kind of content in the `block content` section the background color gets painted. I mean let's say I put `<h1> Hi </h1>` inside the block content, then the background would get  painted behind it.

Answer (score -1):

I found out the answer

Just put this in your css (over the whole body)

```css
width: 100vw;
min-height: 100vh;
```